# Passing Background Image in Canvas - Signature -ColdFusion

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, html5-canvas, drawing, drawable

I have been playing with zksignature which works fine for passing a signature through etc.  Was wondering how to pass a background image through it as well.  Idea is to perhaps draw on the background and then save the background and drawing.

I can load a background into the canvas with css- but it is not passed through as part of the drawn image.

Anyone have any thoughts? or isthere a simple javascript drawing function out there?

Files: 
bg.cfm - loads the canvas with background
blank_signature.js - is the javascript
bg2.cfm - is returned page (currently only shows the drawing - not background as well)

BG.cfm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <script src="blank_signature.js"></script>

</head>

<style>
    .verd15 { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: normal; color: ##000000;}
    .verd14 { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 14pt; font-weight: normal; color: ##000000;}
    .verd13 { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 13pt; font-weight: normal; color: ##000000;}
    .verd10 { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: normal; color: ##000000;}
    .verd9 { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 9pt; font-weight: normal; color: ##000000;}
    .verd8 { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: normal; color: ##000000;}

    body, canvas, div, form, input {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #wrapper {
        padding: 10px;
    }
    canvas {
        position: relative;
        margin: 1px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        border: 1px solid #3a87ad;
        background-image: url(hb.jpg); 
    }
    h1, p {
        padding-left: 2px;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #controlPanel {
        margin: 2px;
    }
    #saveSignature {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<body>


<cfset chars = "abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890">
<cfset strLength = 6 >
<cfset urandout = "">
<cfloop from="1" to="#strLength#" index="i">
<cfset rnum = ceiling(rand() * len(chars))>
<cfif rnum EQ 0 ><cfset rnum = 1></cfif>
<cfset urandout = urandout & mid(chars, rnum, 1)>
</cfloop>
<cfset chars = "abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890">
<cfset strLength = 6 >
<cfset srandout = "">
<cfloop from="1" to="#strLength#" index="i">
<cfset rnum = ceiling(rand() * len(chars))>
<cfif rnum EQ 0 ><cfset rnum = 1></cfif>
<cfset srandout = srandout & mid(chars, rnum, 1)>
</cfloop>


<br>


    <div id="wrapper">
    <form>
    <span class=verd13>
    <b>Draw:</b> 
    </span>
    <br><br>

        <div id="canvas">
            Canvas is not supported.
        </div>

        <script>
            zkSignature.capture();
        </script>
        <!--- <img id="newSignature" alt="Saved image png" src="hb.jpg">
         <img id="bg" src="hb.jpg"> --->

        <table border=0 cellpadding=3 width=300>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <button type="button" onclick="zkSignature.send()" class=verd13>&nbsp; &nbsp; Sign &nbsp; &nbsp;</button>
        </td>
        <td align=right valign=top>
        <button type="button" onclick="zkSignature.clear()" class=verd10> Clear </button>
        </td>
        </tr></table>
        <cfoutput>          
            <input type="hidden" id="uid" value="#urandout#">
            <input type="hidden" id="signid" value="#srandout#">    
        </cfoutput>
        </form>

    </div>
    <table align=center class=verd10>
<tr><td>
</td></tr></table>

</body>
</html>
```

blank_signature.js

```
var zkSignature = (function () {

var empty = true;

return {
    //public functions
    capture: function (){
            var parent = document.getElementById("canvas");
            parent.childNodes[0].nodeValue = "";

            var canvasArea = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvasArea.setAttribute("id", "newdraw");
            parent.appendChild(canvasArea);

            var canvas = document.getElementById("newdraw");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

            if (!context) {
                throw new Error("Failed to get canvas' 2d context");
            }

            screenwidth = screen.width;

            if (screenwidth < 480) {
                canvas.width = 402;
                canvas.height = 409;
            } else {
                canvas.width = 402;
                canvas.height = 409;
            }

            var disableSave = true;
            var pixels = [];
            var cpixels = [];
            var xyLast = {};
            var xyAddLast = {};
            var calculate = false;
            //functions
            {
                function remove_event_listeners() {
                    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', on_mousemove, false);
                    canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
                    canvas.removeEventListener('touchmove', on_mousemove, false);
                    canvas.removeEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);

                    document.body.removeEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
                    document.body.removeEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);
                }

                function get_board_coords(e) {
                    var x, y;

                    if (e.changedTouches && e.changedTouches[0]) {
                        var offsety = canvas.offsetTop || 0;
                        var offsetx = canvas.offsetLeft || 0;

                        x = e.changedTouches[0].pageX - offsetx;
                        y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY - offsety;
                    } else if (e.layerX || 0 == e.layerX) {
                        x = e.layerX;
                        y = e.layerY;
                    } else if (e.offsetX || 0 == e.offsetX) {
                        x = e.offsetX;
                        y = e.offsetY;
                    }

                    return {
                        x : x,
                        y : y
                    };
                };

                function on_mousedown(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();

                    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', on_mousemove, false);
                    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
                    canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', on_mousemove, false);
                    canvas.addEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);

                    document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
                    document.body.addEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);

                    empty = false;
                    var xy = get_board_coords(e);
                    context.beginPath();
                    pixels.push('moveStart');
                    context.moveTo(xy.x, xy.y);
                    pixels.push(xy.x, xy.y);
                    xyLast = xy;
                };

                function on_mousemove(e, finish) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();

                    var xy = get_board_coords(e);
                    var xyAdd = {
                        x : (xyLast.x + xy.x) / 2,
                        y : (xyLast.y + xy.y) / 2
                    };

                    if (calculate) {
                        var xLast = (xyAddLast.x + xyLast.x + xyAdd.x) / 3;
                        var yLast = (xyAddLast.y + xyLast.y + xyAdd.y) / 3;
                        pixels.push(xLast, yLast);
                    } else {
                        calculate = true;
                    }

                    context.quadraticCurveTo(xyLast.x, xyLast.y, xyAdd.x, xyAdd.y);
                    pixels.push(xyAdd.x, xyAdd.y);
                    context.stroke();
                    context.beginPath();
                    context.moveTo(xyAdd.x, xyAdd.y);
                    xyAddLast = xyAdd;
                    xyLast = xy;

                };

                function on_mouseup(e) {
                    remove_event_listeners();
                    disableSave = false;
                    context.stroke();
                    pixels.push('e');
                    calculate = false;
                };

            }

            canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', on_mousedown, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', on_mousedown, false);

    }
    ,
    save : function(){

            var canvas = document.getElementById("newdraw");
            // save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");


    }
    ,
    clear : function(){

            var parent = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var child = document.getElementById("newdraw");
            parent.removeChild(child);
            empty = true;
            this.capture();

    }
    ,
    send : function(){

            if (empty == false){

            var canvas = document.getElementById("newdraw");
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var signid = document.getElementById('signid').value;
            var uid = document.getElementById('uid').value;

            var dataform = document.createElement("form");
            document.body.appendChild(dataform);
            dataform.setAttribute("action","bg2.cfm");
            dataform.setAttribute("enctype","multipart/form-data");
            dataform.setAttribute("method","POST");
            dataform.setAttribute("target","_self");
            dataform.innerHTML = 
            '<input type="hidden" name="image" value="' + dataURL + '"/>' + 
            '<input type="hidden" name="uid" value="' + uid + '"/>' + 
            '<input type="hidden" name="signid" value="' + signid + '"/>'; 
            dataform.submit();

            }
    }

}

})()

var zkSignature;
```

bg2.cfm

```
<style>
    .verd15 { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: normal; color: ##000000;}
    .verd14 { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 14pt; font-weight: normal; color: ##000000;}
    .verd13 { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 13pt; font-weight: normal; color: ##000000;}
    .verd10 { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: normal; color: ##000000;}
    .verd9 { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 9pt; font-weight: normal; color: ##000000;}
    .verd8 { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: normal; color: ##000000;}

    body, canvas, div, form, input {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #wrapper {
        padding: 10px;
    }
    canvas {
        position: relative;
        margin: 1px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        border: 1px solid #3a87ad;
        background-image: url(hb.jpg); 
    }
    h1, p {
        padding-left: 2px;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #controlPanel {
        margin: 2px;
    }
    #saveSignature {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<cfoutput>
<br>
ID: #signid#
<br><br>
User: #uid#
<br>

<br>

<cfset chars = "abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890">
<cfset strLength = 6 >
<cfset randout = "">
<cfloop from="1" to="#strLength#" index="i">
<cfset rnum = ceiling(rand() * len(chars))>
<cfif rnum EQ 0 ><cfset rnum = 1></cfif>
<cfset randout = randout & mid(chars, rnum, 1)>
</cfloop>

<cfset nimage = imageReadBase64(image)>
<cfimage 
 source="#nimage#"
 destination="#randout#.png" 
 action="write"
   nameconflict="overwrite">




<img src="#randout#.png" border=1>
</cfoutput>
<br>
<br>
<li><a href="bg.cfm">Back</a>
<br>
```

Comment: Is this possible?